Estimating an induction motor slip
i need to extract a fans' RPM using the AC current frequency. I don't have the means to actually measure RPM but i have some nameplate values for the motor.
given that i have the slip rating at full load i wanted to estimate the slip for smaller loads (the motor is connected to a VSD) so i thought even though the relation may not be linear to estimate the slip at lower loads as (rated slip at full load) * (load ratio)
is this a legit approximation? or am i making more harm in adding this linear approximation to the slip? I'd be happy for any input :)

Please list the fan and other information about the signal.

I don't have a specific fan in mind i'm aiming to create some kind of general calculation and i assume ill be able to get the full load slip from various fans nameplate.
